# How do I split a big HTML file into multiple files without breaking the tags?

Tags: html, file

I have a downloaded Discord chat with 50k messages. The file is 210MB and looks like this:

```html
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="chatlog">
            <div class="chatlog_message-group">
                <div class="chatlog_messages">
                    <div class="chatlog_message">
                        <div class="chatlog_embed">
                        CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatlog_message-group">
                <div class="chatlog_messages">
                    <div class="chatlog_message">
                        <div class="chatlog_embed">
                        CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
```

My goal is to split the file into multiple files, while not breaking the HTML tags.

EDIT: So after processing, I would have file1.html looking like [this](https://hastebin.com/raw/uyidofipen), file2.html looking like [this](https://hastebin.com/raw/arodawaled), and so on.

Comment: You do you mean that you want to separate this one html file into different files and then link them together to 1 file?

Comment: Do you want to process this page and export as separate working HTML files or do you want to split into multiple HTML files to be included in one?

Comment: I want separate files. FILE.html should become FILE1.html, FILE2.html, FILE3.html...

Comment: How will you prevent breaking the `<body>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Python](https://www.python.org/) this could be handled fairly simple:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from lxml import etree, html
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path

parser = html.HTMLParser()

header= "<html><body>\n";
footer = "</body></html>\n";
i = 1;

file = "chatlog.html"

try:
    tree = html.parse(StringIO(Path(file).read_text()), parser)

    try:
    # target and print all <div class="chatlog_message-group"> elements and subelements
        for element in tree.xpath('//div[@class="chatlog_message-group"]'):
            # create and open a new file for writing
            f = open("chat" + str(i) + ".html", "w+")

            # retrieve the HTML outerHTML of the current element
            f.write(header + etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8") + footer)
            f.close()
            i += 1

    except etree.XPathEvalError as details:
        print ('ERROR: XPath expression', details.error_log)

except etree.XMLSyntaxError as details:
    print ('ERROR: parser', details.error_log)
```

The packages mentioned in the first lines of code need to be installed via "pip" (Package installer for Python) which is documented [here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

Please note that the entire HEAD part is not going to be present in the target files. If you need to add stylesheets etc., either do this manually inside the `header` variable or you would need to tweak the script to extract the HTML `head` first and add this prior to adding the HTML content to each file.

---

**Multiple messages per file**

Multiple messages can be added to one file with the use of the `%` (modulo) operator. Just set the variable `messagesPerFile` to the numbers of messages to be included in one file and you are good to go.

Updated code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from lxml import etree, html
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path

parser = html.HTMLParser()

header= "<html><body>\n"
footer = "</body></html>\n"
i = 1
fi = 1

messagesPerFile = 3

file = "chatlog.html"

buffer = ""

try:
    tree = html.parse(StringIO(Path(file).read_text()), parser)

    try:
    # target and print all <div class="collectionDiv"> elements and subelements
        for element in tree.xpath('//div[@class="chatlog_message-group"]'):

            buffer += etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8")

            if i % messagesPerFile == 0 and i > 0:   
                f = open("chat" + str(fi) + ".html", "w+")
                f.write(header + buffer + footer)
                f.close()
                fi+=1
                buffer = ""

            i+=1
        # if remaining elements are still in the buffer, write them out
        if buffer != "":
            f = open("chat" + str(fi) + ".html", "w+")
            f.write(header + buffer + footer)
            f.close()

    except etree.XPathEvalError as details:
        print ('ERROR: XPath expression', details.error_log)

except etree.XMLSyntaxError as details:
    print ('ERROR: parser', details.error_log)
```

Comment: This works, but I would like to have more messages in each HTML file it makes, not just one.

Comment: @PBJF just added a second code sample to include multiple messages in one file.  Great this worked!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build your ultimate file from a series of *includes*.

For example, using PHP - other server-side scripting languages are available - your **Main File** might look like this:

```
<?php

echo '

  <html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
      <div class="chatlog">
      ';

      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/chatlogs/chatlog-1.php';
      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/chatlogs/chatlog-2.php';

      echo '
      </div>
    ...
  </body>
  </html>
';

?>
```

and your includes might look like this:

**chatlog-1.php**

```
    <div class="chatlog_message-group">
        <div class="chatlog_messages">
            <div class="chatlog_message">
                <div class="chatlog_embed">
                CONTENT 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**chatlog-2.php**

```
    <div class="chatlog_message-group">
        <div class="chatlog_messages">
            <div class="chatlog_message">
                <div class="chatlog_embed">
                CONTENT 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to SPLIT a file, not merge it.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarification. Probably I'd just use a text editor (like Sublime Text 3) for this, but I understand that it depends on context.